# Automated build: MSTest takes very long to complete on Team Foundation Build server

Tags: tfs, build-automation, mstest, xunit

I have the following issue.

- I have an automated build setup on a tfs build server (TFS 2010)
- The workspace of the build definition contains 2 solutions I've configured to be built
- When building, the build takes very long to complete (over 35 minutes)
- After some searching I've found that MStest is causing the build to take so long. I've enabled logging (see a shortened version of the log at the end of this post) on MStest.exe (http://my2centsontfs.blogspot.be/2012/03/enabling-logging-on-mstestexe.html) and I see that everything goes very smooth up to a certain point. Then during 30minutes the log only spits out the following 2 statements every 20seconds:

V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:22:17.542, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:22:37.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer

after those 30minutes, MsTest just continues working for 1more minute and exits with code 1. And then my build finishes.

I don't know if the following is relevant, but just to be complete:

- One of the solutions contains XUnit tests
- I've installed VS (2010) on the build server and also a plugin to enable running XUnit test from within VS (or tfs for that matter), it's called XUnitForVS and be found here: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/5648 (I've installed version 1.2). Running the tests from within VS is not a problem.
- Thanks to the plugin the automated build picks up my XUnit test and runs them

Can anyone explain what is happening during those 30 minutes that MSTest seems to do nothing. And how can I solve this problem. My build + tests should actually take only 35 - 30 = 5 minutes.

Thanks

Stif

my (shortened because the actual log file is 7MB) MStest log file:

```
V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.318, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Runner.Main: starting...
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.725, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi:Tmi
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.896, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, New test type record: {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.896, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}: Satellite DLL found OK
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.896, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}: TIP 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestTip, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Tip, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}: Satellite DLL loaded OK
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}: assosiated with editor {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, New test type record: {3451566b-e89a-4b09-ac24-6cb67cfb8a04}
 W, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, TestType: {3451566b-e89a-4b09-ac24-6cb67cfb8a04}: Cannot load a Satellite DLL because the Registry Value 'SatelliteBasePath' cannot be found. Will attempt to use default values for name and icon.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {3451566b-e89a-4b09-ac24-6cb67cfb8a04}: Satellite DLL found OK
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:25.912, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {3451566b-e89a-4b09-ac24-6cb67cfb8a04}: TIP 'XUnitForVS.UnitTestTip, XUnitForVS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
 W, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, TestType: XUnit Test for VS, {3451566b-e89a-4b09-ac24-6cb67cfb8a04}: No VsEditor was defined for this TestType. This situation should be examined and probably corrected before shipping.
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, New test type record: {7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6}
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6}: Satellite DLL found OK
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6}: TIP 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Manual.ManualTestTip, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.ManualTest.Tip, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6}: Satellite DLL loaded OK
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6}: assosiated with editor {0cc3387e-c1f8-96de-b5fd-a93d48110d16}
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, New test type record: {982b8c01-1a8a-48f5-b98a-67ee64bc8687}
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {982b8c01-1a8a-48f5-b98a-67ee64bc8687}: Satellite DLL found OK
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 10:53:26.053, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Test type {982b8c01-1a8a-48f5-b98a-67ee64bc8687}: TIP 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Generic.GenericTestTip, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.GenericTest.Tip, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

..BLABLABLA...

V, 1368, 24, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(ControllerExecution.TestMessageSender)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: successfully invoked job processor for job 'run id {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, test 'CanWriteLog' with id c99d2be9-9a58-4724-9e5e-cf266a199b82: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Passed'
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener.OnProcessReceivedTestMessage: Handling message 'run id {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, test 'CanWriteLog' with id c99d2be9-9a58-4724-9e5e-cf266a199b82: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Passed'
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.AddOrUpdateResult: AcceptChanges: started.
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.AddOrUpdateResult: AcceptChanges: finished.
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener.OnProcessReceivedTestMessage: Handling message 'Run {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, Test {c99d2be9-9a58-4724-9e5e-cf266a199b82}: Completed'
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, AggregationManager: No collector event sink for Session '{78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}'; no need to raise data collection event.
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener.OnProcessReceivedTestMessage: Handling message 'Run {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, Test {8e12d9e6-017d-40e1-af89-1f802cc1b119}: Started'
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 25, 2012/08/03, 10:54:49.833, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(LocalRunMessageListener.TestMessageReceiver)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: successfully invoked job processor for job 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessageBulk'
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:54:57.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:54:57.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:55:17.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:55:17.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:55:37.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:55:37.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 10:55:57.552, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer


... continues during 30minutes every 20 seconds...


V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:23:37.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:23:37.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:23:57.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:23:57.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:24:17.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:24:17.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:24:37.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener: RestartTimer
 V, 1368, 15, 2012/08/03, 11:24:37.541, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerExecution: Sent heartbeat to listeners
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:24:50.025, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundSpecialJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ReceivedTestMessageWrapper>(ControllerExecution.TestMessageReceiver).TryEnqueueJob: invoking special job checker for job 'ReceivedTestMessageWrapper for test message 'run id {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, test 'StartAndStopServiceAsInLiveEnvironment' with id 8e12d9e6-017d-40e1-af89-1f802cc1b119: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Timeout' from agent 'IXB20725TFB431''
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:24:50.025, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundSpecialJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ReceivedTestMessageWrapper>(ControllerExecution.TestMessageReceiver).TryEnqueueJob: successfully invoked special job checker for job 'ReceivedTestMessageWrapper for test message 'run id {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, test 'StartAndStopServiceAsInLiveEnvironment' with id 8e12d9e6-017d-40e1-af89-1f802cc1b119: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Timeout' from agent 'IXB20725TFB431''
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:24:50.025, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundSpecialJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ReceivedTestMessageWrapper>(ControllerExecution.TestMessageReceiver).TryEnqueueJob: isSpecial = False
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:24:50.025, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ReceivedTestMessageWrapper>(ControllerExecution.TestMessageReceiver).TryEnqueueJob: Queuing job 'Type Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ReceivedTestMessageWrapper: ReceivedTestMessageWrapper for test message 'run id {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}, test 'StartAndStopServiceAsInLiveEnvironment' with id 8e12d9e6-017d-40e1-af89-1f802cc1b119: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Timeout' from agent 'IXB20725TFB431''


...BLABLABLA...

V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: TestRunFinished.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: TestRunFinished: disconnecting listener...
 I, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalRunMessageListener.Dispose: Disconnecting the listener.
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: invoking job processor for job 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry'
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: successfully invoked job processor for job 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry'
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: StopProcess.
 V, 1368, 23, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(LocalRunMessageListener.TestMessageReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: Shutting down agent processes
 I, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy: received Shutdown command.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy.StopMonitorThread: starting.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy.StopMonitorThread: set m_monitorStopped.
 I, 1368, 11, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy.ProcessMonitorThread: Stop event was set. Shutting down.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.431, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy.Shutdown(OutOfProcessTestAgentStrategy): waiting for agent process to exit ...
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.494, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, OutOfProcessStrategy.Shutdown(OutOfProcessTestAgentStrategy): done waiting for agent process to exit, success = True
 V, 1368, 13, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerObject: RunQueueThread exit
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor).TryEnqueueJob: Queuing job 'Type Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry'
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor).Flush: Waiting for 1 jobs to be processed
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor).TryEnqueueJob: Queuing job 'FlushJob'
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: invoking job processor for job 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry'
 V, 1368, 116, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: successfully invoked job processor for job 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry'
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor).Dispose
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ControllerQueueEntry>(ControllerObject.RunQueueMessageProcessor).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(ControllerObject.DataCollectionEventReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(ControllerObject.DataCollectionEventReceiver).Dispose
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(ControllerObject.DataCollectionEventReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(AgentProcessManager.DataCollectionEventReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(AgentProcessManager.DataCollectionEventReceiver).Dispose
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.SynchronizedEventInfo>(AgentProcessManager.DataCollectionEventReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: Cleanup is done.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, TMI.TestRunEndUpdateProxies: Removed proxy for run 78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.TestRunEndUpdateProxies: finished successfully.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.525, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.SaveResults(runId): starting
 V, 1368, 12, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.587, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, DeploymentQueue: Deployment thread exiting.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.SaveResults(runId): done, successfully
 I, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, GetObjectsNoLockT(): select * from result where runid_column = convert('78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d', 'System.Guid').
 I, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, GetObjectsNoLockT(): 400 records for runid_column = convert('78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d', 'System.Guid').
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.TestRunEndInternal: finished.
 V, 1368, 118, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(LocalRunMessageListener.TestMessageReceiver)+ExternalJob.ProcessJob: successfully invoked job processor for job 'IXB20725TFB431: Run {78ddd80e-17b2-4055-b4bd-4a56c6b8054d}: Completed'
 V, 1368, 23, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(LocalRunMessageListener.TestMessageReceiver).Dispose
 V, 1368, 23, 2012/08/03, 11:25:20.962, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestMessage>(LocalRunMessageListener.TestMessageReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 I, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:22.775, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, TestFormatsConverter.LoadAsCurrentVersion: D:\bld\A2\B11\TestResults\svc-tfs_IXB20725TFB431 2012-08-03 10_53_33_Any CPU_Release.trx is already the current file format.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.Dispose: starting
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.Dispose: calling Dispose on proxies...
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, ControllerProxy: Dispose is called.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: Dispose(True) is called.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: EnsureNoActiveRuns
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: StopProcess.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: Cleanup is done.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, LocalControllerProxy: Dispose(True) is done, disposed.
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.Dispose: calling Dispose on TIPs...
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.Aggregation.FileDataMessage>(FileDataReceiver.FileDataMessageReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.Aggregation.FileDataMessage>(FileDataReceiver.FileDataMessageReceiver).Dispose
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, BackgroundJobProcessor<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.Aggregation.FileDataMessage>(FileDataReceiver.FileDataMessageReceiver).DoAbort: Clearing 0 queued jobs and 0 jobs waiting to be queued
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Tmi.Dispose: finished...
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Runner.Main: Exiting with exit code 1
 V, 1368, 1, 2012/08/03, 11:25:41.712, IXB20725TFB431\MSTest.exe, Runner.Main: finished.
```

Comment: Are you sure there are only xUnit tests? Those test type GUIDs don't look correct to me. Check for coded UI tests or data-driven unit tests.

Comment: Also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/9db6377a-25ab-4c54-94b9-13472b38aefc

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure though there were only xUnit test in the solution. Anayway, we're using Visual Studio 2012 now and TeamCity as our build server. Much better support for Xunit tests...